# Doing Facebook Requests directly without the built-in UI

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, request

I wanted to confirm if this is possible. I want to publish "User To User Requests" directly to the open graph action with my own UI  (specifically the friend selector).

My friend selector does follow the platform guidelines (ie do not allow users to select all users at once). My question is that can I publish these requests directly without having to use any of the FB UIs including the request dialog preview (we are going to show our own preview).

This is to be built on iOS. The primary reason we want to use our own UI is because our design team feel that the popups hinder UX on mobile and they want to make it seamless. Their reasoning is a design issue that probably up for another discussion all together, but what I want to know is about using the requests api without using the native FB ui.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply, YES, yes you can do this and then post the request to each friend using the id's of the friends selected by the User. All you have to do is just retrieve the friend list retrieve selected user ids and POST to them the requests.